# should Class.getResourceAsStream be closed?

Tags: java

I was wondering if this is required since when I use this method, the file is being read from the classpath. Does "not closing" it lead to a memory leak.

How can I test for such memory leaks?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are assuming that `Class.getResourceAsStream()` will always return a stream that points to a file inside your class' JAR file. This is incorrect. Your classpath may also contains folders, in which case `Class.getResourceAsStream()` will return a `FileInputStream`. Some other class loaders might also return other type of resources, such as remote files (in the case of a URLClassLoader).

Even in the case of a JAR file, it is possible that the implementation maintain, by whatever mean, a persistant view inside the JAR file to the compressed bytes of the file you are accessing. Maybe it is holding upon a memory mapped `ByteBuffer`...

Why take the chance? You should always close streams (and any other Closeable, actually), no matter how they were given to you.

Note that since Java 7, the preferred method to handle closing *any* resource is definitely the try-with-resources construct. It correctly handles several corner cases that are very hard to manage in hand written code, and yet it is almost as easy to write for you as if you had simply forgot about closing the resource. For example, you may use code like this:

```
    try (InputStream in = Class.getResourceAsStream("someresource.txt")) {
        // Use the stream as you need to...
    }

    // Then forget about it... and yet, it has been closed properly.
```

As for detecting leaks, the best strategy is to obtain a memory dump at the time the VM is shut down, then analyze it with some tool. Two popular tools are [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) and [Eclipse mat](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/).

Comment: Is there a more cleaner way to do this? I have >8 files to open and just adding try block for each of them make code quite unreadable.

Comment: @damndemon AFAIK there is no such thing out-of-the-box in JDK. There's however some libraries out there that provide helpers for that and/or you can easily write such helper by yourself. See [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41016827/array-or-collection-of-autocloseable-in-java8) for some possibilities.

Comment: You may also be interested in giving a look at [this article](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/trywithresources.html#:~:text=Syntantic%20Sugar%20Demystified), which explains the internals of the try-with-resources construct. It is really just syntactic sugar that gets replaced by the compiler by the equivalent Java code.

Answer (score 8):

As a rule of thumb you should close all streams (and ay other types that provide close functionality).  It can lead ro resource leaks (memory is one type of resource).

Although there is automatic garbage collection that reclaims memory eventually when an object is no longer referred to, it might still hold native resources that might not be released.  Also, if some other long-lived object (e.g. the classloader) keeps a hold on the resource, it will not be claimed by the garbage collector.

If your program is short lived, or f you only open a small number of resources, you might not run into problems, but resource leaks are hard to detect in long-running applications.

Answer (score 6):

The type returned is an inputstream so, regardless the concrete implementation (which could change from version to version), you have a close() method that imho should be called.

No matter if that method is actually doing something useful with the current version.